# How do I propagate gem configuration file on all my machines

Tags: ruby, rubygems

How do I propagate gem configuration file (.gemrc) on all my developer machines (say 10 of them)

```
e.g. gem: --no-ri --no-rdoc
```

Answer (score 1):

You may decide to sync .gemrc together with some other dotfiles using one of the dotfiles cookboks out there. Or write a small one by youself that set's up your .gemrc.

Comment: I was wondering if there is something which would setup my dev environment.

Answer (score 0):

I think technologies like chef and puppet are unsuitable in this scenario. The setup and configuration of development environments should come from the source code control system.

My tools of choice are:

- [rvm](https://rvm.io/) <-- Used to control the ruby version and "gemsets" or collections of gems used by a project at runtime
- [Gem bundler](http://bundler.io/) <-- Uses a "Gemfile" to install all the gems required by your program

For example the following commands will define my desired ruby version and a "gemset" container called "demo"

```
rvm --ruby-version ruby-2.0.0-p247@demo
bundle init
<add some gems to Gemfile>
bundle install
```

Will generate the following files which can be committed into source control:

```
├── Gemfile
├── Gemfile.lock
├── .ruby-gemset
└── .ruby-version
```

On a fresh machine, developers run "bundle install" to obtain a copy of the same gems.

Extra notes:

- [Berkshelf](http://berkshelf.com/) is another useful tool. It's a bundler for chef cookbooks.

Comment: I am not worried about rvm or bundle, I just need to propagate .gemrc to a new set of machines